# ReactCSSTransition on table rows and empty table state

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to implement a table in ReactJS with the following features:

- initially empty
- rows  are dynamically added and removed
- when there are no rows, an empty state (e.g. a box saying "Table empty") should be displayed
- when a row is removed, there should be a fade out transition
- when the first row is added, there should be no fade out transition on the empty state

I came up with two approaches using ReactCSSTransitionGroup.

### 1. Wrap only rows into ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Codepen: https://codepen.io/skyshell/pen/OpVwYK

Here, the table body is rendered in:

```
renderTBodyContent: function() {
var items = this.state.items;
if (items.length === 0) {
  return (
    <tbody><tr><td colSpan="2">TABLE EMPTY</td></tr></tbody>
  );
}
const rows = this.state.items.map(function(name) {
  return (
    <tr key={name}>
      <td>{name[0]}</td>
      <td>{name[1]}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
return (
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    component="tbody"
    transitionName="example"
    transitionEnter={false}
    transitionLeave={true}>
      {rows}
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
);}
```

The issue is that the last row to be removed does not get the fade out transition before disappearing since the ReactCSSTransitionGroup is not rendered when `item.length === 0`.

### 2. Wrap table body into ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Codepen: https://codepen.io/skyshell/pen/RpbKVb

Here, the entire `renderTBodyContent` method is wrapped into ReactCSSTransitionGroup within the `render` method:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  component="tbody"
  transitionName="example"
  transitionEnter={false}
  transitionLeave={true}>
    {this.renderTBodyContent()}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

And the `RenderTBody` method looks like:

```
renderTBodyContent: function() {
var items = this.state.items;
if (items.length === 0) {
  return (
    <tr><td colSpan="2">TABLE EMPTY</td></tr>
  );
}
const rows = this.state.items.map(function(name) {
  return (
    <tr key={name}>
      <td>{name[0]}</td>
      <td>{name[1]}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
return rows;}
```

The issue is that the empty state gets animated too.

Any suggestions on how to obtain the desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a render state for "table empty"? I would think the fact that there are no rows in the table is indicator enough that the table is empty. It's self evident. :)

Comment: I think for the type of control you are looking for you will want to use the low level React Transition Group. This will add lifecycle methods to your component. After the last animation you will have a callback function where you can check the length of items. If it is zero set a flag in state that will toggle the empty message. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you realseanp for your pointers. Using the low level API and TweenMax instead of CSS transitions, I came up with the following solution. First, introduce a `Row` component:

```
var Row = React.createClass({
  componentWillLeave: function(callback) {
    var el = React.findDOMNode(this);
    TweenMax.fromTo(el, 1, {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0, onComplete: callback})
  },

  componentDidLeave: function() {
    this.props.checkTableContent();
  },

  render: function() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name[0]}</td>
        <td>{name[1]}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

Then populate the table based on an `isEmpty` flag:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: [],
      isEmpty: true
    };
  },

  addRow: function() {
    var items = this.state.items;
    var firstName = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
    var lastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
    items.push([firstName, lastName]);
    this.setState({items: items, isEmpty: false});
  },

  removeLastRow: function() {
    var items = this.state.items;
    if (items.length != 0)  {
      items.splice(-1, 1);
      this.setState({items: items});
    }
  },

  checkTableContent: function() {
    if (this.state.items.length > 0) {
      this.setState({isEmpty: false});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({isEmpty: true});
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  },

  renderTBodyContent: function() {
    if (this.state.isEmpty) {
      return (
        <tr><td colSpan="2">TABLE EMPTY</td></tr>
      );
    }
    var that = this;
    const rows = this.state.items.map(function(name) {
      return <Row
               key={name}
               name={name}
               checkTableContent={that.checkTableContent} />;
    });
    return rows;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>Add row</button>
        <button onClick={this.removeLastRow}>Remove row</button>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <ReactTransitionGroup
            component="tbody"
            transitionName="example"
            transitionEnter={false}
            transitionLeave={true}>
            {this.renderTBodyContent()}
          </ReactTransitionGroup>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/skyshell/pen/yMYMmv